# regex to find part of string that contains letters+dot/number/underscore

Tags: regex

I need to extract usernames from strings.

For example:

```
My username is John.Johnson123

Add me: John_Johnson123

You can write to me at: JohnJohnson123
```

What regex can I use to extract the usernames?

Comment: `[\w.]+` ? ... does this work?

Comment: Is there any other limiting criteria for what a username is? Like Tim says, `[\w.]+` would match any of what look like the usernames in the examples, but would also match all the other words on those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here, we can for instance have an expression similar to:

```
The username is\s+([^\s]+)
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/d6J8yE/1/)

Or:

```
The username is\s+([A-Za-z0-9_.]+)
```

Or just like [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen)'s advice in the comment:

```
The username is\s+([\w.]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try using string split here to avoid a formal regex entirely:

```js
var input = 'The username is John.Johnson123';
var username = input.split('The username is ')[1];
console.log(username);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to match the end of each line for any character that isn't a space.

```
/^The username is ([^ ]+)$/gm
```

See an example here: https://regex101.com/r/N8Hnni/1